# Frequency calculations on subgroups of pandas-groupby, insertion of new rows and rearrangement of columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, transform, frequency

I need some help with performing a few operations over subgroups, but I am getting really confused. I will try to describe quickly the operations and the desired output with the comments.

(1) Calculate the % frequency of appearance per subgroup

(2) Appear a record that does not exist with 0

(3) Rearrange order of records and columns

Assume the df below as the raw data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'store':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                 'branch':['A','A','C','C','C','C','A','A','C','A'],
                 'products':['clothes', 'shoes', 'clothes', 'shoes', 'accessories', 'clothes', 'bags', 'bags', 'clothes', 'clothes']})
```

The grouped_df below is close to what I have in mind but I can't get the desired output.

```
grouped_df=df.groupby(['store', 'branch', 'products']).size().unstack('products').replace({np.nan:0})

# output:
products      accessories  bags  clothes  shoes
store branch                                   
1     A               0.0   0.0      1.0    1.0
      C               0.0   0.0      1.0    0.0
2     C               1.0   0.0      1.0    1.0
3     A               0.0   2.0      1.0    0.0
      C               0.0   0.0      1.0    0.0

# desirable output: if (1), (2) and (3) take place somehow...
products      clothes  shoes  accessories  bags
store branch                                   
1     B             0      0            0     0  #group 1 has 1 shoes and 1 clothes for A and C, so 3 in total which transforms each number to 33.3%
      A          33.3   33.3            0     0
      C          33.3    0.0            0     0
2     B             0      0            0     0
      A             0      0            0     0
      C          33.3   33.3         33.3     0
3     B             0      0            0     0  #group 3 has 2 bags and 1 clothes for A and C, so 4 in total which transforms the 2 bags into 50% and so on
      A            25      0            0    50
      C            25      0            0     0
# (3) rearrangement of columns with "clothes" and "shoes" going first
# (3)+(2) branch B appeared and the the order of branches changed to B, A, C
# (1) percentage calculations of the occurrences have been performed over groups that hopefully have made sense with the comments above
```

I have tried to handle each group separately, but i) it does not take into consideration the replaced NaN values, ii) I should avoid handling each group because I will need to concatenate afterwards a lot of groups (this df is just an example) as I will need to plot the whole group later on.

```
grouped_df.loc[[1]].transform(lambda x: x*100/sum(x)).round(0)
>>>
products      accessories  bags  clothes  shoes
store branch                                   
1     A               NaN   NaN     50.0  100.0  #why has it transformed on axis='columns'?
      C               NaN   NaN     50.0    0.0
```

Hopefully my question makes sense. Any insight into what I try to perform is very appreciated in advance, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [@Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) who tried to help out with this question a day before I post my answer, I managed to find a solution.

To explain the last bit of the calculation, I transformed every element by dividing it with the sum of counts for each group to find the frequency of each element 0th-level-group-wise and not row/column/total-wise.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['store', 'branch', 'products']).size()\
    .unstack('branch')\
        .reindex(['B','C','A'], axis=1, fill_value=0)\
            .stack('branch')\
                .unstack('products')\
                    .replace({np.nan:0})\
                        .transform(
                            lambda x: x*100/df.groupby(['store']).size()
                                   ).round(1)\
                            .reindex(['clothes', 'shoes', 'accessories', 'bags'], axis='columns')
```

Running the piece of code above, produces the desired output:

```
products      accessories  bags  clothes  shoes
store branch                                   
1     B               0.0   0.0      0.0    0.0
      C               0.0   0.0     33.3    0.0
      A               0.0   0.0     33.3   33.3
2     B               0.0   0.0      0.0    0.0
      C              33.3   0.0     33.3   33.3
3     B               0.0   0.0      0.0    0.0
      C               0.0   0.0     25.0    0.0
      A               0.0  50.0     25.0    0.0
```

Comment: I still believe that unstacking and restacking so many times is not the most pythonic way to bring the object to the desired format and I will welcome any other answer that uses a more elegant and sophisticated code. To give an idea, my mind goes to astype('category') and reindex(level='branch') for example, but I have not reached the point to be competent with categorical index yet.